# service td-agent start failed, GLIBC conflict on amazon linux

Tags: fluent, fluentd, amazon-linux

On my NAME="Amazon Linux AMI" VERSION="2018.03" box I tried to install the td-agent according to https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/install-by-rpm, using the commands in https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-amazon2-td-agent3.sh  . It installed successfully, but then 
`service td-agent start` failed with

```
Starting td-agent: /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.4)
```

First I hoped to fix it by erasing `glibc-devel.x86_64`, and in fact it then started and came back with exit code 0, but this was only because the td-agent got erased, too ...

Comment: I gave up on this one. Now I'm spinning up a docker image (FROM fluent/fluentd:debian), this works. Another option is to use a RHEL ami.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue. I tried with old version of fluentd,it worked.
This one `curl -L https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-redhat-td-agent2.sh | sh`
But the issue here is this old version doesn't have elastic search plugin in it. If you don't need to send your log output to elastic search then you can use the old version.